# Perl in place edit within a script

Tags: perl, regex

I need to edit a file in place **within** a perl script, so the oft used one liner:

```
perl -p -e s/<value>/<value>/ig
```

will not work for this situation. How do I get the same results from within a perl script?

```
open(CRONTAB, "+<file" || die "...";

while (<CRONTAB>) { 
   if ($_ =~ /value/) {  
      s/^\#+//;  
      print "$_\n";  
   }  
}
```

My print is showing exactly what I want. It's just the in place edit that I'm looking for.

Comment: You might get better answers on http://StackOverflow.com If you want it moved, flag it for moderator attention. If you want to maintain ownership, make sure your accounts are associated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
do {
  local $^I='.bak'; # see perlvar(1)
  local @ARGV=("file");
  while(<>){
    s/<value>/<value>/ig;
    print;
  }
};
```

Beware though: `$^I` like perl's `-i` isn't crashproof.

Comment: This seems to jive with what I've seen on other sites for a way to in-place edit. I was hoping for something as fast and painfree as the oneliner but this works too. Much thanks.

Comment: aaarrrghhh.  s/jive/jibe/ - "jive" is a style of music or dance.  the word you are looking for is "jibe" - "Jibe \Jibe\, v. i. [...] 2. To agree; to harmonize. [Colloq.] --Bartlett.".  sorry, just one of the things that bug me like people spelling the two words "a lot" as one word "alot".

Comment: s/// will replace regex. What if I want to delete(not replace with blank line) a line that match the regex. Also How to avoid backups?

Comment: @balki you should create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit appear pretty simple.  Have you considered simply using [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) with the -i option?

Comment: I've not considered it. I've never used sed before within a perl script. I'd prefer to do it using perl if possible. I suppose I could backtick the perl -p -e statement in the script too, but it's kind of ugly. Thanks for the thought, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, based on the translation of `-i` in [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = "something";
my $extension = '.orig';
while (<>) {
    my $backup;
    if ($extension !~ /\*/) {
        $backup = $filename . $extension;
    }
    else {
        ($backup = $extension) =~ s/\*/$filename/g;
    }
    rename $filename, $backup;
    open my $outfile, '>', $filename;
    select $outfile;
    s/^\#+// if /value/; 
}
continue {
    print;  # this prints to original filename
}
select STDOUT;
```

Comment: Seriously too much work, given that `$^I` is the precise equivalent for the command line `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

use [File::Inplace](http://search.cpan.org/~chipt/File-Inplace-0.20/lib/File/Inplace.pm)

Also, it has commit/rollback after you've got all your changes in place for a file....